# Ruby on rails next button to link to the next position number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, crud

I have rails application and i want to add next button
I have unit and inside it theres position

I want when the user press at the next button to link to the next position number

```
create_table "units", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "unit_type"
    t.string "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "section_id"
    t.integer "position"
    t.index ["section_id"], name: "index_units_on_section_id"
  end
```

Here is my unit show

```
<%= form_for [@unit, @attempt] do |f| %>
       <%= f.text_area :body,id: "editor" %>
       <%= f.hidden_field :log,id: "ans"%>

      <%= f.submit 'Run', type: "button" ,id: "equal"%>
      <%= f.submit "Next"%>
```

For example I am now in the unit 1 that have position 1, i want when i press next to take me to unit # that have position 2 and so

Here is my unit model

```
class Unit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :section
  has_many :attempts, dependent: :destroy
  
  def attempt_for(user)
    attempts.find_by_user_id(user)
  end
end
```

attempt model

```
class Attempt < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :unit
end
```

inside attempt controller

```
def create
    
    @attempt = @unit.attempts.new(attempt_params)
    @attempt.user = current_user
    if @attempt.save
      array = Unit.where(position: 1).pluck(:id)
      index_a = array[1]
      redirect_to unit_path(index_a), notice: "good jpb!"
    else
      redirect_to unit_path(), alert: "Try again!"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I you want to use multiple submit buttons I think you need to use the button tag:

```
  button_tag 'Run', type: :submit, name: 'pressed_button', value: 'run'
  button_tag 'Next', type: :submit, name: 'pressed_button', value: 'next'
```

Now, on your controller, you can detect which button was pressed, `param[:button_pressed]` will be either `run`, `next` or I think `nil` and you can act differently depending on that.

Comment: I have unit.position. How can i like the next button to the next position number?

Comment: You can always do something like `Unit.where('position >= ?', index_a).order(position: :asc).first`. If you want to avoid the extra request, you can play with some custom SQL string and use the `LEAD` window function to get the record and the id of then next element https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead

Comment: I got this error undefined local variable or method `index_a' for #<AttemptsController:0x00007fb0b00819d0>

Comment: you have this line in your code `index_a = array[1]`, I was just following that, there you would put the current object's ID.

Comment: What's the question mark here? position >= ?'

Comment: Oh ok! Next button goes back to the same page http://localhost:3000/units/1

Comment: The question mark is used for escaping sql values to prevent sql injection (it's replaced with the value of 'index_a'. It's going back to the same page because you probably didn't change the id where you are redirecting the user, you can use the code from my first comment to get the next Unit object and then you need to do `redirect_to that_object`

Comment: Unit.where('position >= ?', index_a).order(position: :asc).first it gives me array. I want single value

Comment: `.first` returns an object, not an array, If you want a value (and not an object), you can do `.first.id` por example. I suggest you read this guide to understand how to use ActiveRecord https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html